# Incorrect expression "In that moment"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I was doing an exercise and I found this one: Correct one word in the incorrect expression "In that moment, the door opened" (the exercise highlights "In that moment" part). However, I think it is good, I don't know what is wrong with this.

Thanks.

Comment: This is Off Topic General Reference/Proofreading/"homework". What they want you to do is change ***in** that moment* to ***at** that moment*. Questions at this level belong on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe they think it should be **at that moment**, interpreting **moment** as a point in time rather than a brief period of time.

My mind could wander for a moment, and in that moment something could happen, so I don't think you can say unequivocally that the original is wrong.